# How to show retrieved data from php on particular click item using jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am new to Jquery. I am trying to display the fetched data w.r.to clicked item.
Now, in below example how to display the products[0] and products[1] to span's element of clicked item.

For example - expected output:

```
item1   1   2
item2   3   4
```

HTML:

```
 <table>
    <tr>
        <td><a href=""  myval="item1">item1</a>
            <span class="qty1"></span>
            <span class="qty2"></span>
        </td>   

    </tr>
<tr>
    <td><a href=""  myval="item2">item2
            <span class="qty1"></span>
            <span class="qty2"></span>   </td>    
    </tr>
<tr>
    <td><a href=""  myval="item3">item3
             <span class="qty1"></span>
            <span class="qty2"></span>      </td>
    </tr> 

    </table>
```

jQuery:

```
 $('a').click(function(){
          var node=$(this);
        var item = node.attr('myval');  

      $.post('month_copy.php', {"bcode":item,"month":"February"}, function(data){

      var products = data.split("|");
     node.find(".qty1").html(products[0]);
     node.find(".qty2").html(products[1]);
});  
    });
```

month_copy.php:

```
echo 1."|".2 //item1
echo 3."|".4; //item2
```

I know there is something wrong in jQuery, please suggest me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`td` is not child of `a` and `.find` works for children.

```
$('a').click(function(){
          var node=$(this);
        var item = node.attr('myval');  

      $.post('month_copy.php', {"bcode":item,"month":"February"}, function(data){

      var products = data.split("|");
     node.closest('td').find('.qty1').html(products[0]);
     node.closest('td').find('.qty2').html(products[0]);
});  
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.One Question instead of td if there are span element with classname, then how to do it.

Comment: @user007 could you please update your question that I can see where the spans are?

Comment: @user007 I edited the answer. don't forget to mark as answer ;)